# Syncing the documents and files from two accounts on one mac via iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I have two accounts on my mac. One for fun, one for work, but there is overlap in some of the files I use between the two, so I want to have all files in my Documents folder accessible to both accounts.

For this I figured that if I synced the two mac accounts with the same iCloud account, Documents and Desktop would also be synced. It seems like that is not the case. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the approach does work. It just needed a little extra time to get started :)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question you asked. Can you enhance by describing what you actually did to get it work (even if it simply was to log in into the same iCloud account from both accounts on the Mac)?

Comment: @nohillside iCloud Drive sometimes takes a loooong time to start syncing. They said "I figured if I synced two mac accounts with the same iCloud account, [iCloud Drive] would also be synced. It seems like that is not the case." They were almost certainly mistakenly thinking it wasn't working, when in fact it just needed to wait.